# Ordering posts by anniversary using only day and month

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, meta-query, order, date

I defined a custom field named *crimedate* using standard date format `Y-m-d`. I defined the filters to make ordering by this date work in the post list of the backend, which works fine.

Now I need the possibility to show posts ordered by anniversary, using only day and month of the *crimedate*, but I don't know how to do that:

```
function crimes_columns($columns) {
    $columns['crimedate'] = 'Crime date';
    $columns['crimeanniversary'] = 'Crime anniversary';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'crimes_columns');

function crimes_show_columns($name, $post_id) {
    switch ($name) {
        case 'crimedate':
            // show whole date
            echo get_post_meta($post_id, "crimedate", true);
            break;
        case 'crimeanniversary':
            // show only anniversary in format dd/mm
            $date = get_post_meta($post_id, "crimedate", false);
            echo substr($date,6)."/".substr($date,4,2);
            break;
    }
    return $row_output;
}
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column',  'crimes_show_columns');

add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_sortable_columns', 'crimes_add_custom_column_make_sortable' );
function crimes_add_custom_column_make_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['crimedate'] = 'crimedate';
    $columns['crimeanniversary'] = 'Crime anniversary';
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'crimes_orderby_meta' );
function crimes_orderby_meta( $query ) {
    if(!is_admin())
        return;
 
    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');
 
    if( 'crimedate' == $orderby ) {
        $query->set('meta_key','crimedate');
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value');
    }
    else if( 'crimeanniversary' == $orderby ) {
        // ¿¿¿ what to do here ???
    }
}
```

Is it possible to sort dates only by day and month ignoring the year in hook `pre_get_posts`? Or do I have to save days and month in two separte fields to make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible by using `pre_get_posts` alone. But you don't have to use separate fields for the date.

`WP_Query`, although doesn't provide a simple query arg that would sort the posts by month and day only, you can use the [`posts_orderby` filter hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_orderby/) to modify the `ORDER BY` clause (i.e. `ORDER BY <the part here>`) for sorting the posts.

### Working Example

1. In the `pre_get_posts` hook, set the `meta_key` to `crimedate`:

   ```php
   // In crimes_orderby_meta():

   elseif ( 'crimeanniversary' == $orderby ) {
       $query->set( 'meta_key', 'crimedate' );
   }
   ```
2. Then on the `posts_orderby` hook, you can use the `STR_TO_DATE()` function in MySQL to sort the posts by the month and day of the meta value:

   Note that I purposely used a static *leap year*, which means `29/02` (Feb 29<sup>th</sup>) always comes after `28/02` (Feb 28<sup>th</sup>), when the sort order is `ASC`.

   ```php
   add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'posts_orderby_crimeanniversary', 10, 2 );
   function posts_orderby_crimeanniversary( $orderby, $query ) {
       if ( is_admin() && 'crimeanniversary' === $query->get( 'orderby' ) ) {
           global $wpdb;

           $order = ( 'ASC' === strtoupper( $query->get( 'order' ) ) ) ? 'ASC': 'DESC';

           // This means, we still sort by the date, but we "recreate" the date using
           // the year 2020 (or any leap year), and month and day from the meta value.
           $orderby = "STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( '2020-',
               MONTH( {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value ), '-',
               DAY( {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value
           ) ), '%Y-%m-%d' ) $order";
       }

       return $orderby;
   }
   ```

I hope that helps, and please correct these issues in your code:

- In `crimes_add_custom_column_make_sortable()`:

  ```php
  $columns['crimeanniversary'] = 'crimeanniversary';  // like this
  $columns['crimeanniversary'] = 'Crime anniversary'; // not this
  ```
- In `crimes_show_columns()`:

  ```php
  get_post_meta($post_id, "crimedate", true)  // like this
  get_post_meta($post_id, "crimedate", false) // not this
  ```

  And just remove that line with `$row_output` — which is not defined.
- And don't forget the *fourth* parameter here:

  ```php
  add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'crimes_show_columns', 10, 2); // like this
  add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'crimes_show_columns');        // not this!
  ```

Comment: That solution worked great. Thanks also for all your code hints!